# Image is not loading in github static page, but loading in local computer

Tags: html, css, github

https://github.com/AmanShahwaz/carousel
This is the link of static page, I have tried to make a carousel but somehow images are not showing up.
First i am trying to update the image url in css so as to load single image in page, if anyone of you can help me out in this it will be highly appreciated.

Later i'll need to obviously update the path in javascript file as well. But first please help with css part

Comment: It will only load image 2 and 3

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.